# Crystal Reports break space

Tags: crystal-reports

How can I not split my table into two pieces in the Crystal Reports file.
Thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/088HR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Go to File, Page Setup...
Increase page size.

If default printer doesn't support that page size,, use a different printer.
Or, if you don't intend to print, simply turn on 'Dissociate Formatting Page Size and Printer Paper Size'